# C floating point number notation

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point

I noticed that this code compiles but I have no idea why:

```
int main() {
  double z = 0.000000000000001E-383DD;
}
```

But I'm not sure what the `DD` at the end of the number means.  I've looked through the standard but there's no mention of this.

I got this number from the following command:

```
$ gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null
#define __DBL_MIN_EXP__ (-1021)
#define __FLT_MIN__ 1.17549435e-38F
#define __DEC64_DEN__ 0.000000000000001E-383DD
...
```

Might this be a GCC extension?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right it's a [GCC extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Decimal-Float.html#Decimal-Float) to indicate 64-bit [*decimal* floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_floating_point) literals.

Other extension suffixes:

- [Complex literals](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Complex.html#Complex), e.g. `1.0i`, `1.0j`, `1.0fi`, etc. This purely a GCC extension and the standard C99 way is to use the macro `I` (`1.0*I`, `1.0f*I`, etc.)
- [Additional floating point types](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Floating-Types.html#Floating-Types), which are purely a GCC extension:

  - `1.0w` → `__float80` (80-bit binary floating point)
  - `1.0q` → `__float128` (128-bit binary floating point)
- [Decimal floating point types](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Decimal-Float.html#Decimal-Float), which is based on the proposal [*N1312: Extension for the programming language C to support decimal floating-point arithmetic*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1312.pdf):

  - `1.0df` → `_Decimal32` (32-bit decimal floating point)
  - `1.0dd` → `_Decimal64` (64-bit decimal floating point)
  - `1.0dl` → `_Decimal128` (128-bit decimal floating point)
- [Fixed-point types](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Fixed_002dPoint.html), which is based on the proposal [*N1169: Extensions to support embedded processors*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1169.pdf):

  - `0.5hr`, `0.5r`, `0.5ulr`, etc. → `_Fract` types (fixed point types with magnitude ≤ 1)
  - `5.0hk`, `5.0k`, `5.0ulk`, etc. → `_Accum` types (fixed point types)

Comment: Thanks for the links, they made it much easier to understand your answer.

Comment: Why CMSIS DSP doesn't use fract or accum?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a GCC extension to support [decimal float](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Decimal-Float.html). The literal has type `_Decimal64`, but is converted when assigned to the `double` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it stands for a densely packed Decimal of 64 bits?

[This wikipedia article section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal64_floating-point_format#Densely_packed_decimal_significand_field) looks like it matches the name of the define, no?