# Where can I find a listing of C++11 type prefixes/suffixes?

Tags: c++, types, c++11, prefix, user-defined-literals

Could somebody point me to a complete listing of language type prefixes/suffixes?

prefix examples:

```
auto s1 (u8"I'm a UTF-8 string.");
auto s2 (u"This is a UTF-16 string.");
auto s3 (U"This is a UTF-32 string.");
auto s4 (R"(RAW \ STRING " )");
auto s5 (L"wide string");
//etc..
//*I've only seen prefixes like this for strings.
```

suffix examples:

```
auto n1 = 7.2f;
auto n2 = 7.2d;
auto n3 = 100L;
auto n4 = 10000LL;
//etc..
```

All my search attempts send me to "making your own user defined literals".
Perhaps these instances have a specific name that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are not "type" prefixes/suffixes, these are literal prefixes/suffixes, as they are applied on literals (string literals, number literals, ...). They don't have specific names, because they aren't that interesting ☺.

The built-in prefixes and suffixes in C++11 are:

- Integers:

  - `12U`, `12L`, `12UL`, `12LU`, `12LL`, `12ULL`, `12LLU`, `12u`, `12uL`, `12Lu`,  `12uLL`, `12LLu`, `12l`, `12Ul`, `12lU`, `12ll`, `12Ull`, `12llU`, `12ul`, `12lu`, `12ull`, `12llu`
- Floating points:

  - `1.0f`, `1.0F`, `1.0l`, `1.0L`
- Characters:

  - `L'x'`, `u'x'`, `U'x'`
- Strings:

  - `u8"xxx"`, `u"xxx"`, `U"xxx"`, `L"xxx"`, `R"(xxx)"`, `u8R"(xxx)"`, `uR"(xxx)"`, `UR"(xxx)"`, `LR"(xxx)"`

In particular, `1.0d` is not a built-in C++11 suffix. Some compilers e.g. GCC may also have extensions for other number suffixes, see [C floating point number notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786338/c-floating-point-number-notation).

---

Relevant lexical grammar:

(§2.14.2 Integer literals)

> *unsigned-suffix*: one of
>
> > `u U`
>
> *long-suffix*: one of
>
> > `l L`
>
> *long-long-suffix*: one of
>
> > `ll LL`

(§2.14.4 Floating literals)

> *floating-suffix*: one of
>
> > `f l F L`

(§2.14.3 Character literals)

> *character-literal*:
>
> > `'` *c-char-sequence* `'`
> >     `u'` *c-char-sequence* `'`
> >     `U'` *c-char-sequence* `'`
> >     `L'` *c-char-sequence* `'`

and

(§2.14.5 String literals)

> *string-literal*:
>
> > *encoding-prefix*<sub>opt</sub> `"` s-char-sequence<sub>opt</sub> `"`
> >     *encoding-prefix*<sub>opt</sub> `R` *raw-string*
>
> *encoding-prefix*:
>
> > `u8`
> >     `u`
> >     `U`
> >     `L`

Comment: A mention of user-defined literals would be nice.

Comment: @LucDanton: Well I believe OP already knows what user-defined literals are (s/he mentioned it in the second-last paragraph), so I just leave it out.

Comment: What if someone else is interested in literals in a wider sense and stumble on that question via a search?